# Ruby on Rails - model validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem with simple model validation.
Entering materials without SKU is getting me error message:

> NoMethodError in Materials#create   undefined method `empty?' for
>   nil:NilClass

[image]
material.rb:

```
class Material < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :sku, :presence => true
end
```

materials_controler.rb (create part only):

```
# POST /materials
  # POST /materials.json
  def create
    @material = Material.new(material_params)


    respond_to do |format|
      if @material.save
        format.html { redirect_to @material, notice: 'Material was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @material }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @material.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `@units` also in your create method

Answer (score 3):

Your `@units` instance variable is `nil` in `create` action. You should set it the same way as you do in `new` or `edit` actions after your records fails validation.

Comment: I was missing `@categories` and `@units`. Thank you.